# Picard's method of succesive approximations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

> Construct first $3$ succesive approximations $x_0,x_1,x_2$ for the following Cauchy problems:

$$x'=-x+t^2$$
$$x(0)=2$$

I have no idea how to start this... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compute successively the functions
$$
x_0(t)=x_0, ~~ x_{n+1}(t)=x_0+\int_0^tf(s,x_n(s))\,ds
$$
using your function $f(t,x)=-x+t^2$.

Comment: So my $x_0(t) = 2$?

Comment: Also when does the bounds of the integral changes? When $t_0$ is not 0?

Comment: Yes. And if $x(t_0)=x_0$, then the lower integral boundary is $t_0$ instead of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your equation as

$$
x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t[-x(u) + u^2]{\rm d}u \tag{1}
$$

The ideas is to approximate this with the expression

$$
x_{n + 1}(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t[-x_n(u) + u^2]{\rm d}u \tag{2}
$$

Start with

> $x_0 = x(0) = 2$

Replace that in (2) and you get

$$
x_1(t) = 2 + \int_0^t [-x_0(u) + u^2]{\rm d}u = 2 - 2t  + \frac{t^2}{3} \tag{3}
$$

> $x_1 = 2 - 2t + t^2/3$

Evaluate this in Eq. (2) again and get

$$
x_2(t) = 2 + \int_0^t[-x_1(u) + u^2] = 2 - 2t + 2t^2 + \frac{t^3}{3} - t^4
$$

I will leave the other two for you to complete